# How to create a repository in Azure DevOps with HTTP Trigger in Logic

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Please provide the detailed steps to create a repository in Azure DevOps with HTTP Trigger in Logic App.

I tried to setup HTTP trigger & it doesn't create repository.
Please provide complete steps to achieve the requirement.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

**`Design:`**

[image]

**`Url`**: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/oauth2/v2.0/token`

**`Headers:`**

```
Content-Type:

application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

**`Body:`**

```
grant_type=password&client_id=e7c9f&client_secret=ucM8Q&scope=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default&username=M365x56209219.onmicrosoft.com&password=Welc
```

**`Now in HTTP2:`**

[image]

**`Url:`**

```
https://dev.azure.com/Oraganisationname/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

**`Headers:`**

```
Authorization :

Bearer body('HTTP')['access_token']
```

**`Body:`**

```
{
  "name": "RithwikRepository",
  "project": {
    "id": "1fb22858-5722"
  }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]